# WP8/Win8 Store App - Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

Justed tried to add multiplayer support for a monogame project. I wanted to use libgren but as far as I could see there are no networking classes available on windows phone. Is there any workaround? How can send and recieve tcp and udp packets on windows phone? The same question applies to Windows 8 Store Apps.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Building-real-time-connected-apps-with-Windows-Phone-8-and-SignalR

Comment: So there is no workarounds for working with sockets.

Answer (score 0):

There are sockets for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.aspx . If you are targeting WP8 (not 8.1) you will need to use the Silverlight Windows Phone 8 sockets - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202874(v=vs.105).aspx